# using Locust.io for REST web service

Tags: performance-testing, spring-restcontroller, spring-oauth2, locust

I wanted to use Locust for performance testing on Spring Rest WebService, where each service is secured by the token.

is anyone tried to do the same by nesting task sets?

How can we maintain the same token for all the request from single user?

is it possible to go to the task on response from other task?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario. If you know what the token is in advance, you can do:

```
def on_start(self):
    """ on_start is called when a Locust starts, before any task is scheduled """
    self.access_token = "XYZ" # method 1
    # self.login() # <-- method 2
```

Otherwise you could call something like a login method that would authenticate your user, and then store the resulting token on `self`.

Since on start happens before any tasks, I never had to worry about nesting task sets.

If you need things to happen in a certain order within tasks, you can just run something like:

```
@task(1)
def mytasks(self):
    self.get_service_1()
    self.get_service_2()
```